# App exit and Open not working as expected

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have made a simple app with 3 activities:
1. Login
2. Rating
3. Summary

The login activity allows Google sign in. If the user is already signed in I start the Rating activity. Code is as below

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Rating.class);
startActivity(i);
```

This part works fine. Now in the Rating activity I check if the user has submitted the rating for the day. I use SharedPreferences to store any previous rating information. I also have a node API working at the back end to record the rating. If the app is not able to find a local SharedPreference for the rating details I do a GET request from the API to cross verify. If the rating info is available for the day, the Summary Activity will be opened.

In addition I have added a functionality to quit the app by pressing the back button from either the Rating Activity or the Summary Activity. Code is as below

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        System.gc();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
    }
```

The problem here is, I successfully exit the App when I hit the back button. But the next time I open the app (without clearing it from the recent apps) the app directly opens at Rating activity. It doesn't pass through the cycle of **Login -> check user logged in -> Rating.**

Now I again quit by pressing the back button. And I open the App again. This time it passes through the cycle *Login -> check user logged in -> Rating.**

This continues. Every alternate time I quit and open, the cycle runs as expected.

EDIT: I also have another problem. While debugging with my phone, every time 2 instances of the App gets listed in my home screen with the same name and icon. Could this be something to do with the issue? However in checking the Apps list it shows only one app with the name.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call finish() on the positive button instead of declaring an intent? Calling finish() inside an activity quits the app and terminates it.

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Exit")
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("no", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
            }).show();
}
```

Comment: Let me try that and get back in a bit.

Comment: Tried i out. The app doesn't quit the first time i press back. It kind of refreshes the Rating activity and then again when i hit back it quits. But this time when i open the app, it goes through the proper life cycle.

Comment: Getting this error -> Cannot resolve method 'setPositiveButton(java.lang.String, anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)'